# Promise not waiting to resolve

Tags: javascript, promise

I just heard about promises and it sounds... promising (ok I'm leaving).

I would expect the following code to show:
- before `initVariables`
- before `initVariables` - `someName`
- before `initVariables` - `someName` - after `initElements`

But instead I got:
- before `initVariables`
- before `initVariables`
- before `initVariables` - after `initElements`

Anybody to help me? :-)
Thx all! :D

```
var url = "https://opendata.paris.fr/api/records/1.0/search/?dataset=stations-velib-disponibilites-en-temps-reel&rows=100&facet=banking&facet=bonus&facet=status&facet=contract_name"

var test = Object.create(MyTestClass);
console.log(test.testVariable);

let loadVariables = new Promise(function(resolve, reject) {
  test.initVariables(url);
  resolve(test);
  console.log(test.testVariable);
});

loadVariables.then(function(test){
  test.initElements();
});
console.log(test.testVariable);
```

And `MyTestClass` is defined by:

```
var MyTestClass = {

    testVariable: "before initVariables",

    initVariables: function(url) {
        $.getJSON(url, function (result) {
            this.testVariable += " - " + result.records[0].fields.name;
        });
    },

    initElements: function() {
        this.testVariable += " - after initElements";
    }
}
```

Comment: There's a common misunderstanding about promises.  They do NOT have any magical powers to know when some async operation is done.  Instead, they are just monitoring tools and they only know when an async operation is done if you wire them up to tell them when an async operation is done.  Your call to `resolve()` is not wired up to when the async operation inside of `test.initVariables()` is done so it just gets called synchronously and doesn't wait for your async operation to complete at all.

Answer (score 4):

Promises run immediately. The only way they don't resolve/reject immediately is if you do something inside them (like call `$.getJSON`) and only call `resolve/reject` based on the callback from `$.getJSON`.

```
function getJSONP(url) {
  return new Promise(function(resolve, reject) {
     $.getJSON(url, resolve);
  }
}
```

or

```
function getJSONP(url) {
  return new Promise(function(resolve, reject) {
    $.getJSON(url, function(result) { 
       resolve(result);
    });
  }
}
```

It that makes it clearer

You can then do

```
 getJSONP(someURL).then(function(result) {
   console.log(result);
 });
```

Comment: Or just `getJSONP(someURL).then(console.log);` :)

Comment: You mean `....then(console.log.bind(console));` since you have no idea if `console.log` is a plain function or a member function.

Answer (score 0):

`Promise` constructor is not necessary, as `$.getJSON()` returns a jQuery promise object which exposes `.then` function.

`$.getJSON()` is not returned from function at `javascript` at Question. `this` is `jqxhr` jQuery promise object unless set at `context` of `$.ajax()` calls. You can use `Function.prototype.bind()` or `$.proxy()` to set `this` at `.then()` chained to `test.initVariables`, where `$.getJSON(url)` call is returned from function.

```js
var MyTestClass = {

  testVariable: "before initVariables",

  initVariables: function(url) {
    return $.getJSON(url)
  },

  handleResult: function(result) {
    this.testVariable += " - " + result.records[0].fields.name;
    console.log(this.testVariable);
  },

  initElements: function() {
    this.testVariable += " - after initElements";
    console.log(this.testVariable)
  }
}

var url = "https://opendata.paris.fr/api/records/1.0/search/?dataset=stations-velib-disponibilites-en-temps-reel&rows=100&facet=banking&facet=bonus&facet=status&facet=contract_name";

var test = Object.create(MyTestClass);

console.log(test.testVariable);

var loadVariables = test.initVariables(url);

loadVariables
.then($.proxy(test.handleResult, test))
.then($.proxy(test.initElements, test))
.fail(function(jqxhr, textStatus, errorThrown) {
  console.log(textStatus, errorThrown);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js">
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

To explain the observed result, the expected result is missing the effect of asynchronous actions. Here are some rules that may help:

1. Promise executor functions are called ***synchronously*** when a new promise is created.  When execution continues after a `new Promise( executor)` statement or expression, the executor function has returned.
2. Promise reaction handlers, supplied by calling `then` or `catch` methods on a promise, are executed ***asynchronously***, in a thread of their own, after the promise they were called on becomes settled.
3. Assume that the `$.getJSON` request makes a call back ***asynchronously*** after a HTTP GET operation has taken place.

Walking through the code:

```
//**  The top of code executing in a thread, say "T1":

var url = "https://www.example.com"

var test = Object.create(MyTestClass);
//** here test.testVariable inherits "before initVariables"

console.log(test.testVariable);

let loadVariables = new Promise(function(resolve, reject) {
  test.initVariables(url);
//** here an asynchronous $getJSON request has been initiated but not completed

  resolve(test);
//**  here the Promise has been synchronously fulfilled,
//**  during execution of this executor function,  with the test object.

  console.log(test.testVariable);

//** here test.testVariable inherits "before initVariables"
//**  because we are still running synchronously in thread "T1" from the top.

});

loadVariables.then(function(test){
  test.initElements();
//** this is some time later, not in thread "T1", because
//** then and catch callbacks are made asynchronously.

});
console.log(test.testVariable);

  // here thread "T1" is still executing,
  // testVariable has not been updated yet.
```

Note that synchronously fulfilling the created promise with the `test` object was not useful in the end. Waiting for the GET request to call back with result data requires reconsideration of the approach to take.

Comment: *"in a thread of their own"*: Web Workers run in threads of their own, but asynchronous code does not.